# Python: Map Not Loading when Loading Facility Names

Tags: python, shapefile, folium

I'm working on an interactive map to plot various medical facilities around the country. I found a suitable shape/database file (along with GeoJson and a CSV) on the web that can be used for this project.

I've managed to get the locations to display on the map, but the facility names do not appear.

According to the sf.fields I print, the names are in field 8, I can print these names as `record.record[8]`, and they will appear in the console.

However, when I set popup as `popup=record.record[8].title()` the map will no longer load. It compiles within the console and returns no errors. What am I missing here?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import folium
import pandas
import shapefile
import csv

with open('VA_Facilities.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(data_file)

myshp = open('data/va_facilities_1.shp', "rb")
mydbf = open('data/va_facilities_1.dbf', "rb")
sf = shapefile.Reader(shp=myshp, dbf=mydbf)
records = sf.shapeRecords()

# Prints the number of records, type of the shape, and fields for the 
dataset
print (len(records))
print (sf.shapes()[0].shapeType)
print (sf.fields)

# Prints the first three records for verification reasons
for record in records[:3]:
    print (record.record[0], record.shape.points[0], record.record[8])


map=folium.Map(location=[47.1164, -101.2996],zoom_start=4,tiles='CartoDB 
positron')
for record in records:
    lat, lng = (record.shape.points[0][1],record.shape.points[0][0])

    folium.RegularPolygonMarker(
    [lat, lng],
    popup=record.record[8].title(),
    fill_color='#EE1C25',
    number_of_sides=5,
    radius=5
    ).add_to(map)


map.save(outfile='Healthcare_Facilities.html')
```

Changing the value of `record.record[0]` back to zero will load the map as usual, but with no names.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The latest version of Folium relies on a raw HTML input, so `parse_html=True` is what must be added to the `popup=` field to have the desired results.

Thanks for the help!